# UIGestureRecognizer on custom UITableViewCell. Tapping fires on multiple cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I've searched high and low to no avail on this odd issue. I have a custom subclassed UITableViewCell. Two views for a front and back, and when tapped the cell flips over. This is done like so:

```
    - (IBAction)cellFrontTapped:(id)sender {
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    if (_cellFlag == 0)
    {
        _cellFlag = 1;
        [UIView transitionFromView:_cellFrontView toView:_cellBackView
                          duration:0.5
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
                        completion:NULL];
        [self performSelector:@selector(cellBackTapped:) withObject:self afterDelay:15.0];
    }
}
- (IBAction)cellBackTapped:(id)sender {
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    if (_cellFlag == 1)
    {
        _cellFlag = 0;
        [UIView transitionFromView:_cellBackView toView:_cellFrontView
                          duration:0.5
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
                        completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

This works fine with just a few cells. Up to a few pages worth. But when I load a larger data set, tapping on one cell flips it over like expected, but also flips over other cells.
I realize this is because the cells are being re-used by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` but I cannot decipher how to prevent it.

I've tried implementing it as one `UIGestureRecognizer`. I've tried utilizing `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.cellFlag == 0)
    {
        [cell cellFrontTapped];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell cellBackTapped];
    }
}
```

These all work to flip the cell properly, but the tap event always flips other cells in the list. The only solution I've found is to not use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyTableViewCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Here's my current subclass implementation:

```
@implementation MyTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Adding the recognizer here produced the same result
    //UIGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellTapped)];
    //tap.delegate = self;
    //[self addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    _cellFlag = 0;
}

- (void)cellFrontTapped {
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    _cellFlag = 1;
    [UIView transitionFromView:_cellFrontView toView:_cellBackView
                          duration:0.5
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
                        completion:NULL];
    [self performSelector:@selector(cellBackTapped) withObject:self afterDelay:15.0];
}

- (void)cellBackTapped {
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    _cellFlag = 0;
    [UIView transitionFromView:_cellBackView toView:_cellFrontView
                          duration:0.5
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
                        completion:NULL];
}

-(void)cellTapped
{
    if (_cellFlag == 0)
    {
        [self cellFrontTapped];
    }
    else
    {
        [self cellBackTapped];
    }
}

@end
```

Here's the `configureCell:atIndexpath:

```
- (void)configureCell:(MyTableViewCell*)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *t = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //here i set the labels and such
    cell.cellBackAmountLabel.text = [t.amount formattedAmount];
    //added 
    if ([self.flippedCellIndexes containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:cell.cellBackView];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:cell.cellFrontView];
    }
}
```

I'm at a loss. Not using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` makes a significant performance impact in my case. Help!

Comment: How and where do you add the tap action to cell?

Comment: I've tried adding it in 3 places: 1 - The awakeFromNib of the subclass. 2 - in Interface builder (xib file for the subclassed cell) as a tap gesture recognizer with corresponding outlet. 3 - No tap gesture recognizer and instead just utilizing didSelectRow as in my question.

Comment: can you update your current code and show us everything?

Comment: I've added the subclass implementation. What else would you want to see?

Comment: Are you using UITabGestureRecognizer? If you are, why not use `indexPathForRowAtPoint`?

Comment: Right now I'm not using a tap recognizer any more and just trying to use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` for the tap event. Still when I flip the cell, the corresponding dequeued ones flip as well.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you tap a cell for the first time, it works correctly. But if you scroll and you reuse a cell, and if you tap a cell again, the reused cell gets flipped too?

Comment: If I tap any cell, it flips not only itself but dozens of other cells. If I scroll and flip back over any of those cells, it flips them all back over. The timer does the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend separating your model from your view. What this means is that you should keep track of which cells should render as flipped, but not on the cell itself. Lets say you declare an `NSArray` (probably `NSMutableArray`, even) called `flippedIndexes` in your view controller.

If your data set is as big as you say, then probably you should use a sparse array instead of `NSArray`. Sparse arrays can easily be implemented with `NSMutableDictionary`. `NSMutableSet` could also work.

When dequeueing the cell, you would then check which cells should be flipped, probably at that `configureCell:atIndexPath:` method of yours. Basically, if the `indexPath` shows on your sparse array or set you render the cell as flipped. This would imply dropping the `cellFlag` property you have declared on your cell and toggling its state according to the model I've been mentioning. For flipping a cell, check the `flippedIndexes` property for the given `indexPath` and act accordingly. Something like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (![self.flippedIndexes containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        [cell cellFrontTapped];
        [self.flippedIndexes addObject:indexPath];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell cellBackTapped];
        [self.flippedIndexes removeObject:indexPath];
    }
}
```

Here I'm assuming the use of `NSMutableSet` for the `flippedIndexes` property. Notice that this will only work properly if you also check the model in `configureCell:atIndexPath:`, as otherwise you'll have cells magically clearing when scrolling.

Moral of the story is: don't store state information in queued cells.

Comment: I've tried your solution but the same result. Used an NSMutableSet to store flipped indexes. Removed the cellFlag property. I flip one cell and dozens of others are flipped throughout the table.

Comment: What does a flipped cell look like? How does it differ from others?

Comment: Did you make the changes to `configureCell:atIndexPath:`?

Comment: The flipped cell contains several extra labels, an image, and a button. It has a different background color as well. And the flip is animated as shown in the subclass, with a timer to flip it back over after a set time.

Comment: At first sight I would maintain that the problem is in `configureCell:atIndexPath:`. Could you post the code for that?

Comment: Here's the `configureCell:atIndexpath:`

Comment: Added the `configureCell:atIndexPath:` to the question

Comment: You are right, the implementation seems correct. Try understanding whether `containsObject:` is returning what you expected it to. If the cell is being configured after being dequeued it should be rendering properly. We are missing something

Comment: Yes the mutableset contains what we expect, but we are missing something. I also have a problem with this implementation with the timer used to flip the cell back over, as it's in the tableviewcell subclass and won't update my indexes nsmutableset.

Comment: About the timer you can either place it outside the cell or use a delegate on the cell. Something like `cellDidFlip:`. On the view controller you can listen for the delegate notification and clear the set

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. When you call `configureCell:atIndexPath:` the cell has not yet been inserted in the view, so it's not in the view tree. Calling `bringSubviewToFront:` has no effect. Try using visibility instead: `cell.cellBackView.hidden = YES` while at the same time `cell.cellFrontView.hidden = NO`. Do the opposite otherwise.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help. Take the time to accept the answer ;)

Comment: I'll accept it now. Thanks! Also, in the delegate method you mentioned to fix the timer, how would you remove the proper indexPath from the NSMutableSet in cellDidFlip: Another quandary.

Comment: Well, I guess that this is making me rethink my original recommendation. Instead of not storing state in cells which are supposed to be queued make sure that you do proper clean up. If you need to link back to the model you should store the index path with the cell, obviously being careful enough to update it or clear it when the cell is dequeued.

Comment: I used: `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.MyTableView indexPathForCell:cell];` and it works, but how would I implement it otherwise? Is there a delegate method called when the cell's dequeued?

Comment: Tried `prepareForReuse` But once a cell is dequeued the timer that invokes `cellDidFlip:` doesn't fire. This means that any cell that is off screen isn't flipped back over by the timer.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. `prepareForReuse` should still work, but you need to cancel the timer and remove the cell immediately when the cell is dequeued. Like I said before, when using queued cells you need to do proper clean up. That includes pretty much everything that is associated with the cell, in this case the callback setup with the timer.